# ECU/PCM plug pinouts

Tags: wiring, electronic-control-module, ect

I'm trying to find out which pins on a Bosch WE0718881B ECU (For a 2007 Mazda BT-50/Ford Ranger) go to the ECT sensor.

I'm been looking for pinouts of the two plugs on the ECU but getting nowhere.

Is this sort of information published? Otherwise, is it safe for me to just continuity test from the ECT sensor wire back to the ECU connectors?

Ultimately, I'm trying to diagnose a P0118 error.  I've replaced the ECT sensor, used contact cleaner on both the ECT sensor plug and the ECU, but still having issues, hence wanting to check the actual wiring.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Haynes usually has decent electrical diagrams in their manuals.  If you get really desperate cut a bit of insulation back from the back of the ECT connector and check the wiring color, then do the same at the ECU end.  Repair it with good quality friction tape.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd be fine doing a continuity test – with both ends of the cable disconnected there wouldn't be any thing that would be likely to interfere. The suggestion to do a bit of poking around the ECT connector to see if you can see the colors of the wires will help you narrow things down on the other end if you can also see the wires at the ECM end.

There are some online sources of automotive data – at least one of them, but unfortunately I can't remember the name right now – offers a DIY subscription that is priced around the cost of a service manual. It might be worth considering.

It would also be worth doing a search, some of this information is available online, although it is hard to search and it can take some work to sort out whether or not you've actually got the information you're looking for. I did a search for "Bosch WE0718881B ECU pinout" and got quite a few hits. The images are the place where you're likely to have the best luck.